# Get native screen resolution using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile, media-queries

I'd like to get the native screen width on a device to append scripts in the DOM. Is it possible using jQuery ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`window.screen.width`? Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen

Comment: TypeError: window.screen is undefined in Firefox 20 and 21.

Comment: @rebellion Which OS? window.screen works for me on Firefox 21 on OSX: http://i.imgur.com/anwTtVM.png

Answer (score 6):

Sure. You can get the basic width and height using:

```
screen.width;
screen.height;
```

If required, you can also get the pixel ratio (useful if you need to also detect retina displays) by using:

```
window.devicePixelRatio
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width to device width with a css property:

```
width: device-width;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```